# When I use #define two scanf("%d",&two) I get an output 1 after entering 4

Tags: scanf, c-preprocessor

This program tries to get input from user and store it in a macro named two but when I print the macro I get 1 as output....
Why is That?

```
#include <stdio.h>
//declares two 
int two;
//Takes input to store it in two 
#define two scanf("%d",&two)
int main() 
{

      printf("%d\n",two);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: May I recommend not to use the same identifier for a) a variable b) for a macro c) within the definition of the macro?

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is the value returned by scanf. The return value is the number of items scanf successfully filled (1 item in this case). See this reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Comment: Just to clarify (for Mihir's benefit), `#define two scanf("%d", &two)` doesn't "get input from user and store it in a macro"; it merely creates a _preprocessor_ macro named `two` that expands to `scanf("%d", &two)`.   Your mention of `two` in `printf("%d\n",two);` invokes the macro, which then expands into `printf("%d\n", scanf("%d", &two));`, which is where Austin's response picks up.